# "Lose Yourself" chorus confusion

Tags: lyrics

I checked the lyrics in many sources (e.g. [spotify](https://open.spotify.com/track/77Ft1RJngppZlq59B6uP0z)) and listened to the song on various platforms, and I still can't make out what he says in the beginning (or rather the second line) of the chorus.

Every source/site says the following for the chorus (emphasis mine):

> You better lose yourself in the music
> **The moment you own it, you better never let it go**
>
> You only get one shot, do not miss your chance to blow
> This opportunity comes once in a lifetime

but I doubt that's what he says/sings. What I hear instead is:

> You better lose yourself in the music
> **..., makes you move, makes you better, never let it go**
>
> You only get one shot, do not miss your chance to blow
> This opportunity comes once in a lifetime

I'm not a native speaker, so my hearing/understanding might not be perfect, but I can't be that wrong about this chorus. I just don't hear *"The moment you own it, you better never let it go"* in it. What gives?

---

Update 1:

Here are some cuts from the song to analyze the lyrics:

- [Normal](https://whyp.it/tracks/41524/01-eminem-lose-your-self-chorus-issue-normal?token=fpwTP)
- [-25% Speed](https://whyp.it/tracks/41525/01-eminem-lose-your-self-chorus-issue-25-speed?token=2zFcK)
- [-25% Tempo](https://whyp.it/tracks/41526/01-eminem-lose-your-self-chorus-issue-25-tempo?token=iiEk5)
- [-50% Tempo](https://whyp.it/tracks/41527/01-eminem-lose-your-self-chorus-issue-50-tempo?token=Zc8Sl)

---

Update 2:

Digging deeper, I realized there's an [alternative/original](https://soundcloud.com/tyraelarchange/eminem-lose-yourself-original-demo-version-unreleased-version) version of this song. Its chorus is clearer though.

> Lose yourself in this music
> This moment we own it, we won't never let it go (go)
> You better move yourself cause tomorrow's ass can wait
> There is no time, to sit there and procrastinate (you better)

Seeing this might have moved me a little in the direction of thinking *"The moment you own it, you better never let it go"* might be correct, but I still need convincing.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the [LOSE YOURSELF - FROM "8 MILE" SOUNDTRACK](https://www.eminem.com/music/just-lose-it/lose-yourself-8-mile-soundtrack) page is empty :(

Answer (score 1):

The first lyric is correct.
I can say this with reasonable confidence because I recently did a cover of it & to get the timings absolutely right I separated the original vocal out from the rest of the track, so I could hear it very clearly.

Just for fun - 'Imagine if Eminem's Lose Yourself had been done by an old bloke from Yorkshire'. See if you can hear it better in this version. No Eminem samples were used, it's all new recording. The lip-sync isn't great, but I did the whole thing myself, soundtrack & video, in 2½ days ;)

Comment: I listened to the song, and watched and tried to match the lip movements to the lyrics in the chorus part, but can't say I make out the "The moment, you own it" part. Also tried the vocal isolation thing in Audacity, but it didn't help much. The slowed versions that I linked keeps me in doubt. I also tried to contact eminem on twitter to get him update the lyrics on the site. Maybe that will clear the confusion.

Comment: I used Izotope RX to do the separation & VocAlign to perfect the sync to the original vocal… about a $£€ 1,000 worth of advanced audio manipulation software. I'm pretty certain of the result. I'm also an English native speaker, which probably helps ;)